# Smart way to add same library/include paths to different projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, include-path, lib

I know the question may seem really noobish, but actually i have pretty huge coding experience, and it's just that i'm pretty new to Visual Studio (installed VS_2017 just few hours ago) and i'm rly struggling with global options now: i can't find a way to specify location of a library(-ies) for different projects.

I know there r 2 options for every project: "**C/C++ » General » Additional Include Directories**" & "**Linker » General » Additional Library Directories**", but the thing is that i have 3 libraries (atm) and they used in a bunch of different projects (there will be even more projects loaded via git and they all will be using same 2-3 libs)...

So specifying the same directories for every project manually seems very inefficient to me, but i rly can't find any global option for include/lib paths... I googled 'bout "**Tools » Options » Projects and Solutions » VC++ Directories » Include files**" but such feature is deprecated in VS 2017.

SO:

1. i wonder if such feature actually exists in Visual Studio 2017 (or some replacement)
2. i wonder if there is some sideway like some macro maybe which can add library (previously configured paths) to a project via couple clicks (preferably with RegExp syntax for replacement if there is some path specified for one of libs already)

P.S. i know about Environmental variables in Win OS's, but it's not acceptable for me 'cuz it looks unreasonable to trash it with directories which will be used ONLY by VS IDE!

Comment: Have a look at Vcpkg https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/ , it is a convenient way to acquire and build C++ 3rd party libraries on windows and integrate them inside your VC++ project (VS2015 and VS2017). Vcpkg create an enlistment (a tree folder) with all the libraries, from where all your projects can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider referring the below MSDN article
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a494abb8-3561-4ebe-9eb0-6f644a679862/visual-studio-2010-professional-how-to-add-include-directory-for-all-projects?forum=vcgeneral

> Prior to VS2010, VC++ Directories could have been used, but as you
>   mentioned that setting is deprecated now.
>
> VC++ Directories are no longer supported in VS2010 through
>   Tools->Options page. Instead, VS2010 introduces the user settings file
>   (Microsoft.cpp..users.props) to control global settings
>   including Global search path. These files are located at
>   $(USERPROFILE)\appdata\local\microsoft\msbuild\v4.0 directory. Upon
>   migration to VS2010, the custom settings of VC++ Directories from
>   VS2005 or VS2008 are migrated to these user files. These global
>   settings files are imported into all the converted and newly created
>   projects.
>
> Here are the steps to change the settings file through UI:
>
> ·         Open up property manager by clicking on View.Property
>   Manager.
>
> ·         Expand the project node and then the Configuration|Platform
>   nodes, you will see "Microsoft.cpp..users" file for each
>   Configuration|Platform. These are the files for the global settings,
>   similar to the old tools/Options/VC++ Directories.
>
> ·         Multi-Select "Microsoft.cpp..users", right click
>   and bring up the property page window
>
> ·         In the property page window, click on "VC++ Directories"
>   (for example) in the left pane, add new paths for the directories such
>   as "Include Directories". separated by semicolons
>
> ·         Make sure to save the settings before shutting down Visual
>   Studio.
>
> ·         Re-launch Visual Studio and the new settings will be in
>   effect.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sumeet's post, in the *Windows Explorer* the location of the file could easily be found as

> %localappdata%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0

.